# Javascript - style.left will update for subtraction but not addition

Tags: javascript, styles, associativity

```
function moveLeft(obj){ 
    obj.style.left = parseInt(obj.style.left) - 0.5 + "%";
}

function moveRight(obj){
    obj.style.left = parseInt(obj.style.left) + 0.5 + "%";
}
```

The code here is supposed to move my image object to the left and to the right by updating percentages instead of pixels. moveLeft works but moveRight doesn't. Is it something to do
with associativity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you call parseInt() it returns the value rounded down. So you're actually not moving by half percent, but one percent. This way, the best solution is to increment in 1 on every step:

```
function moveLeft(obj){ 
    obj.style.left = (parseInt(obj.style.left, 10) - 1) + "%";
}

function moveRight(obj){
    obj.style.left = (parseInt(obj.style.left, 10) + 1) + "%";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function moveRight(obj){
    obj.style.left = parseInt(obj.style.left) + 0.5 + "%";
}
```

You use style.left instead of style.right

Comment: Tried that, no difference in output :(